# Parse.com OR query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to do get the most recent comments of each result of a query using an OR query because promises are slow and expensive:

```
    var queries = [];
    _.each(videos, function (video) {
        var mostRecentCommentsQuery = video.relation("comments").query();
        mostRecentCommentsQuery.descending("createdAt");

        mostRecentCommentsQuery.include("creator");
        mostRecentCommentsQuery.include("mentions");

        mostRecentCommentsQuery.limit(4);

        queries.push(mostRecentCommentsQuery);
    });

    var commentQuery = new Parse.Query.or.apply(this, queries);
    return commentQuery.find();
```

And getting this error:

```
Failed with: TypeError: function apply() { [native code] } is not a constructor
    at Parse.Promise.when.then.then.then.next_page (functions.js:82:28)
    at e (Parse.js:2:3909)
    at Parse.js:2:3459
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:664)
    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:3410)
    at i (Parse.js:2:2901)
    at b.Promise.is.a.then.g.(anonymous function) (Parse.js:2:2992)
    at e (Parse.js:2:3909)
    at Parse.js:2:3459
```

But doing `var commentQuery = Parse.Query.or.apply(this, queries);` does nothing. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I fixed the initial part; I never checked to make sure that comments had associations to the video's that own them. Unfortunately, this lead to a new issue, where the queries are not limited. E.G:

There are 6 comments on the first video that is returned. The 4 most recent comments should be returned. All 6 are returned, which can lead to slow response times and plain inaccurate data.

Is there a way to enforce the limit of each subquery within an `OR` query?

Comment: Running into a similar issue, did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the limit on the combined query: i.e

```
commentQuery.limit(4);
```